# Dynamic Welcome-File in JSF2

Tags: jsf-2

I am using JSF 2 on Jboss AS 7.  I would like to use some code to decide which home page (/) to show.  I have a servlet (/homePage) that can render the correct page, so if I go to /homePage/ it works well, but I would like to be able to do that at the / url.  How can I set the welcome-page to use a servlet rather than a page?

I have tried building a servlet that listens to all request, and render the correct page is the request is (/), but JSF seems to attempt to resolve the welcome-file before the servlets.

I realize I can just re-direct from a home page (index.xhtml) to /homePage, but that adds a couple more round trips for the browser, and makes the URL look ugly.

Thanks for your help!

Update....here is a servlet that is never called

```
@WebServlet("/homePage")
public class HomePageServlet extends HttpServlet {  
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println("----------HOME PAGE SERVLET CALLED");
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
            dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(HOME_PAGE1);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

and here is my web.xml welcome file list

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/homePage</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

the browser receives a 404 and "----------HOME PAGE SERVLET CALLED" is never printed.

Comment: Could you show what configuration you have used for your servlet?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set `<welcome-file>` to a servlet URL.

E.g.

```
<welcome-file>/index</welcome-file>
```

with

```
@WebServlet("/index")
```

Comment: Balus, thanks for the answer but unfortunately it doesnt seem to work.  I have cleaned out all unrelated filters/servlets, and now just have @WebServlet("/homePage"), and <welcome-file>/homePage</welcome-file>, but the server returns a 404, and the servlet is never called.  This actually used to work on Jboss 6 with JSF 1.2 and seam, but is not on Jboss 7 with JSF2.